# How to automate batch testing in Microsoft LUIS by sending text in a csv file in python

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Like sending questions through a CSV file and getting the mapped intent and entities which can be used for validation in LUIS

Answer (score 0):

We can use [batch testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-batch-test) to test or validate using the files through UI i.e luis.ai. Currently it is not supported programmatic API. Hope this helps!!